# DHCP server can not receive my client in virtual interface

Tags: python, dhcp, ethernet, socket, veth

I'm writing a DHCP server and my own client using socket in Python3.
My client:

```
def client(self):
        print("DHCP client is starting...\n")
        dest = ('<broadcast>', serverPort)
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 25, str("veth0" + '\0').encode('utf-8'))
        #s.bind(('0.0.0.0', clientPort))

        print("Send DHCP discovery.")
        data = DHCP_client.discover_get();
        s.sendto(data, dest)
```

My DHCP server:

```
def server(self):
    print("DHCP server is starting...\n")
    
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST,1)
    s.bind(('', serverPort))
    dest = ('255.255.255.255', clientPort)

    while(True):
        data, address = s.recv(65536)
        print(data)
```

But I can not see any messages captured by server, even though I can see a request from `sudo tcpdump --interface=veth1 -v`

```
    tcpdump: listening on veth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
06:32:10.472938 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 47168, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 277)
    ubuntu.37318 > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:05:3c:04:8d:59 (oui Unknown), length 249, xid 0x3903f326, Flags [none]
          Client-Ethernet-Address 00:05:3c:04:8d:59 (oui Unknown)
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Discover
            Requested-IP Option 50, length 4: 192.168.1.100
```

Do I set anything wrong here? I have no idea why `recv` can't capture anything.
Do you have any advice for me?

I create `veth0` and `veth1` by

```
ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
```